# Configure Apache reverse proxy for wss

Tags: websocket, apache2

(I am sorry that I am not able to format the question better. Some of the fields are not showing).

I am trying to configure Apache so that client browsers from another device/computer from the internet would be able to access it through a tunneling client like ngrok from my local computer. The html page was able to load, other areas have loaded, but wss was not loading.

The browser was giving error:

```
Firefox could not establish connection with
wss://example.com/ws/locationOf_wsfile
```

The following is my Apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # enable HTTP/2, if available
    Protocols h2 http/1.1

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/example.com.key

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"

    DocumentRoot "/usr/share/web_static_files"
    <Directory "/usr/share/web_static_files">
        Options Indexes MultiViews Includes FollowSymLinks
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
   </IfModule>

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5320/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5320/
    ProxyPass /ws-id ws://localhost:8450/ws-id
    ProxyPassReverse /ws-id ws://localhost:8450/ws-id

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.html
    
</VirtualHost>

# Mozilla Guideline v5.4, Apache 2.4.41, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, intermediate configuration, no OCSP
SSLProtocol         all -SSLv3 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder off
SSLSessionTickets   off
```